# Yii2 iterate dataprovider with relations

Tags: iterator, yii2, dataprovider

I need to know how to iterate through a Yii2 dataprovider with relations.

I have a model Asset that has a relationship to another model Make.

```
class Equipment extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    // ...
    public function getMake() {
        return $this->hasOne(Make::className(), ['make_id' => 'make_id']);
    }
}
```

In my controller, I have 2 functions, one to render a grid, and another to export the data to a CSV file.

```
public function actionEquipment()
{
    $searchModel = new EquipmentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    // Store the search model in session
    Yii::$app->session->set('exportEquipmentModel', $searchModel);;

    // Render grid
    return $this->render('equipment', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

public function actionExportequipment()
{
     header('Content-type: text/csv');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="equipment_report-' . date('YmdHi') .'.csv"');

     $searchModel = new EquipmentSearch();
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    // Use the search model from session, or get all        
    if(\Yii::$app->session->get('exportEquipmentModel')) {
        $searchModel = Yii::$app->session->get('exportEquipmentModel');

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(false);
        $dataProvider->setPagination(false);
    }

    // csv header
    $columns =[
        'serial_number',
        'Make',
        'Model',
    ];
    echo  implode(",", $columns) . " \r\n";

    // csv data
    foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $data) {

         $row =[
             $data['serial_number'],
             // TODO: I need to resolve the relation here
             $data['make_id']                     // Works
             // $data->make_id                    // Works
             // $data->make->description          // Does not work
             // $data['make_id']['description'],  // Does not work
             $data['model_id']
         ];

         echo  implode(",", $row) . " \r\n";
    }

}
```

As can be see from the comments in the code, various forms of getting the make->description field is not yielding results.

Comment: If you want value for that field, just use `$data->relationName->desired_field_name`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull, that is what I expected. However, as you can see in my comments, $data->make->description does not work. A var_dump($data->make) returns null, while $data->make_id returns a valid value. I posted my model and relations in the question. If I get the equipment using find, then $equipmentModel->make->description returns a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned : Always check for errors.

My code was correct. However, the data was not what I expected. The dba deleted some of the makes and models after setting off foreign key checks. Therefore, $data->make.

I therefore changed the line

```
$data->make->description
```

to

```
!empty($data->make)?$data->make->description:'Not Set',
```